# Testing views in express js

Tags: testing, node.js, express, bdd, pug

I'm trying to figure out an ideal way to test my views, written in Jade. They contain some logic. For example on the home page if a cookie has been set it should show a button to link to the main console and have option to logout versus if no cookie is set it should show login.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at selenium

http://seleniumhq.org/

And of course the node adapter

https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda

Answer (score 1):

I think that are not [hard bugs to debug](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/17/unified-theory-of-bugs/)(You should see that in the browser window if it happens). But if you really want to I think you have following options:

- Write the tests the way TJ did looking at [his tests](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/master/test). He has written tests for almost everything.
- Doing headless testing use for example [tobi](https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi) or [zombie.js](https://github.com/assaf/zombie). There is also [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/), but this product is not developed in node.js.
- [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)(not developed in node.js) with [soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) like deltanovember pointed out.
- You could use [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) to test all your browsers(client-side javascript). You could also use [YETI](https://github.com/yui/yeti)(using YUI test framework) to test all your code in all the browsers.